# Call functions in other functions

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, call

I am new to functions and I am trying to figure out how to get a value from one function to be   in another. Here's the layout: I defined a function to pull random numbers and place them into the Dictionary:

```
import random

def OneSingletDraw(rng):
    i=0
    g=0
    b=0
    y=0
    r=0
    w=0
    bk=0

    while i<20:
        x = rng.randint(1,93)
        if x<=44:
            g=g+1
        elif 44<x<=64:
            b=b+1
        elif 64<x<=79:
            y=y+1
        elif 79<x<=90:
            r=r+1
        elif 90<x<=92:
            w=w+1
        else:
            bk=bk+1
        i=i+1
    D = {}
    D['g'] = g
    D['b'] = b
    D['y'] = y
    D['r'] = r
    D['w'] = w
    D['bk'] = bk

    return D
```

Now, I defined a second function to give me the number of times the above function got 6 of the above variables. It looks like:

```
def evaluateQuestion1( draw ):
    # return True if draw has it right, False otherwise
    colorcount = 0
    for color in draw:
        if draw[color] > 0 : colorcount += 1
    if colorcount == 6: return True
    else: return False
```

with the last part being:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 1000
    rng = random.Random()
    Q1Right = 0
    Q1Wrong = 0
    for i in xrange(n) :
        D = OneSingletDraw(rng)
        if evaluateQuestion1( D ) : Q1Right += 1
        else: Q1Wrong += 1
    print "Did %d runs"%n
    print "Got question A: total number of colors in bag right %d times, wrong %d times (%.1f %% right)"%(Q1Right, Q1Wrong, 100.*float(Q1Right)/float(n))
```

It outputs something like: Did 10 runs for singlets strategy.
Got question A: total number of colors in bag right 1 times, wrong 9 times (10.0 % right)

So far so good. Now I want to see how many times it gets more r than b. I tried mimicking the second function, but it doesn't recognize b

```
def evaluateQuestion2( draw ):
    # return True if draw has it right, False otherwise
    for r in draw:
        if draw[r] < b : return True
    else: return False
```

How do I get my next function to recognize b from earlier?

Comment: Im not sure I recognize b either. You havent defined it anywhere in the code you have posted. but the problem will almost certainly be with scope. you must define a variable OUTSIDE a function in order for it to persist after the function has finished. how did b get the to the first function? did you pass it in as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop in your second function, you can just compare values corresponding to the `"r"` and `"b"` keys of your dictionary directly:

```
def evaluateQuestion2(draw):
    return draw["r"] < draw["b"]
```

Unrelated to your issue: You can probably streamline your draw code by making the dictionary up front and updating its values, rather than putting the values initially in separate variables and then building the dictionary at the end:

```
def OneSingletDraw(rng):
    D = dict.fromkeys(["g", "b", "y", "r", "w", "bk"], 0) # build the dict with 0 values

    for _ in range(20):  # use a for loop, since we know exactly how many items to draw
        x = rng.randint(1,93)
        if x <= 44:
            D["g"] += 1  # access the value in the dict, using += to avoid repetition
        elif x <= 64:    # no need for a lower bound, smaller values were handled above
            D["b"] += 1
        elif x <= 79:
            D["y"] += 1
        elif x <= 90:
            D["r"] += 1
        elif x <= 92:
            D["w"] += 1
        else:
            D["bk"] += 1

    return D
```

Comment: For that you need to count the results from repeatedly calling the `evaluateQuestion2` function in the loop in your `if __name__ == "__main__"` block.